# Failing to insert elements into unordered_set

Tags: c++

I am developing a graph that uses unordered sets as adjacency sets and have run into an issue when trying to insert edges into the adjacency sets. The issue is that the methods I've written do not seem to insert any edge into the adjacency set of a vertex.

Below is the code of the method's I use to add edges to a vertex.

`addEdge` in **hash-graph.hpp**

```cpp
/**
 * Adds a non-existent, directed, edge from a "tail vertex" to a 
 * "head vertex" by modifying the adjacency set of the "tail vertex".
 * If the passed in edge already exists, the method instead returns
 * false.
 * 
 * @param   tail  the vertex at which the edge starts
 * @param   head  the vertex at which the edge ends
 * @return  false if edge already exists, else true
*/ 
template <class K, class V>
bool HashGraph<K, V>::addEdge(K tail, K head)
{
   Vertex<K, V> vTail = getVertex(tail);
   Edge<K> edge(head);
   return vTail.addEdge(edge);
}
```

`addEdge` in **vertex.hpp**

```cpp
template <class K, class V>
bool Vertex<K, V>::addEdge(Edge<K> edge)
{
    if (this->hasEdge(edge))
        return false;
    adjacencySet.insert(edge);
   return true;
}
```

Could anyone help me fix this issue? Please let me know if you want to see any additional code.

Comment: We need an [MCVE]; your problem is likely in code you haven't shown, like `hasEdge`, the `operator==` or hash function for `Edge`, etc.

Comment: Which set are you expecting the edge to be added to? `vTail` is destroyed when `HashGraph::addEdge` returns.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Oh, good point. `getVertex` should return by reference (which a [MCVE] would at least let us know) and `vTail` should be declared as a reference if you want persistent effects.

Comment: If you're used to programming in languages where the values you pass around are references to objects, you have some re-learning to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am expecting the edge to be added to ``std::unordered_set<Edge<K>> adjacencySet`` in ``vTail``, so I probably go wrong here and I think of ``vTail`` as being a reference to a vertex inside the ``unordered_map`` that holds the vertecies of my graph, but if I understand your comments correctly, ``vTail`` is not a reference.

Comment: `vTail` is indeed a copy of whatever `getVertex` returns.

Comment: @mooncow ether with `auto` or with specific type reference must be declared explicitly in this case. And you may want to use `auto &` here.

Comment: The issue I was having was indeed caused by me not passing the vertex by reference. After modifying relevent methods and variables as suggested by @molbdnilo the ``addEdge`` method works as expected.

Comment: @K.Claesson This isn't your question...